# jQuery - Initially click button twice to increase/decrease div height

Tags: jquery, html, button, click, toggle

I've seen a number of similar posts but still can't pin-point the issue in my simple code. I'm sure it's a simple solution/reason it's doing this..

The idea is for the div to increase in height too 100% of the content, or decrease in height back to the original 150px, based on toggling from button click (variable `$status_on_button`). Initial height as you can see in the jQuery is set to 150px.

**I have to click the button twice INITIALLY to fire the first condition.** Thereafter it works as it's supposed to. If it's at all relevant, the jQuery code is entered into a wordpress plugin which has worked well in the past. My code as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="aboutus_container" style="overflow:hidden;">
  <!--some html elements/paragraphs here-->
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="aboutus_readmore_button">Read more...</button>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // initialise toggle variable to zero and 'aboutus_container' div height
  $status_on_button = 0;
  $('#aboutus_container').css('height', '150px');

  //button click
  $('#aboutus_readmore_button').click(function(){
    if ($status_on_button==0) {
      $('#aboutus_container').animate({height:'150px'}, 500);
      $status_on_button = 1; //toggle button status
    } else {
      $('#aboutus_container').animate({height:'100%'}, 500);
      $status_on_button = 0; //toggle button status
    }
  });

});
```

This is probably going to be an "aha" moment with the answer and probably staring me in the face. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a jQuery expert (not by a long-shot!) but it looks like you set your variable to '0' and then set the height to 150px and then within the function you're checking if the status variable == 0 (which it is on the first iteration!) and so you're setting it to 150px AGAIN on the first click.  Looks like just a logic problem!

Again, I'm no jQuery expert, but I might do it a bit differently - first get the current height of the aboutus_container when you trigger the function with the button click.  For example (pseudocode, because I don't know the jQuery syntax off the top of my head):

```
if(#aboutus_container(height) == 150px) {
     [make it 100%]
}
else {
     [make it 150px]
}
```

Comment: Dude you are 100% right and I had this eureka moment as I finished my post LOL. I answered my own question (see above). Sometimes things are right in your face but your mind makes it complicated. Thanks!

Comment: Ha - Saw that you'd answered your question as I was posting.  I dabble in jQuery so I get caught in the logic flaws a bit too much so it's easy for me to see sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, it just dawned on me. I have to swop the height 100% line and the height 150px line. It must do the 100% height first or it's setting the initial height a second time on first click, which shows no change in div.. eureka. Typing this post helped. I'll leave it here for others that may find it useful.

Here is the corrected jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // initialise toggle variable to zero and 'aboutus_container' div height
  $status_on_button = 0;
  $('#aboutus_container').css('height', '150px');

  //button click
  $('#aboutus_readmore_button').click(function(){
    if ($status_on_button==0) {
      $('#aboutus_container').animate({height:'100%'}, 500);
      $status_on_button = 1; //toggle button status
    } else {
      $('#aboutus_container').animate({height:'150px'}, 500);
      $status_on_button = 0; //toggle button status
    }
  });

});
```

For clarification, these two lines were swopped:

```
$('#aboutus_container').animate({height:'100%'}, 500);

$('#aboutus_container').animate({height:'150px'}, 500);
```